# Using Project specific color palette in React and sharing it to child components by a single reference

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-ui

I have got an SCSS like this

color.scss

```
$conifer: #bae659; // Conifer
$apple: #63c532; // Apple
$jungle-green: #00796d; // Jungle Green
$vivid-violet: #a446ba; // Vivid Violet
$dark-violet: #7d3787; // Dark Violet
$gigas: #4f3398; // Gigas
$mercury: #e2e2e2; // Mercury
$monza: #e00716; // Monza
$mirage: #15152b; // Mirage
$athens-gray: #F3F5F8; // Athens gray
$rock-blue: #A3B0CB; // Rock blue
$nobel: #b3b3b3; // Nobel
$gray-nurse: #E1E6EA; //Gray nurse
```

In my App.tsx

```
import './color.scss'
const App = () => {
  
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<RecipeLanding />} />
          <Route path="ManageRecipe" element={<ManageRecipe />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I need to use these colors in my child components as well. So how can I handle this the best way.

Is there is anyway to use it like this even in child components just by the reference in app.tsx

bgcolor:mystyle.vivid-violet

Comment: Check how you can use React context to pass themes to child components here - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext